# Set transformations image path

Tags: image-transforms

When using image transforms, Craft not only doesn't seem to be outputting the transformed image, but the image path it's then giving back to the template is: `<img src="http://example.com/cpresources/transforms/1" />` which doesn't exist.

I have a upload path defined, which is `http://example.com/assets/uploads/` but obviously it isn't respecting that.

I can't find any docs on where to define the transformations image path so wondered if anyone could shed some light?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Craft doesn't have a setting for defining the transformations image path, they are automatically placed in a subfolder inside your created assets source' path. It could look something like this `_960x540_crop_center-center_70`, if you had a transform like this:

```
{ width: 960, height: 540, mode: 'crop', position: 'center-center', quality: 70 }
```

By default, the url you're seeing is what Craft will return if the transform hasn’t been generated yet. The next time the page is loaded, it should reference the actual image file. [See Brandon's answer here](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/831/141), for a more thorough explanation.

But, if everything is working, you should see the image in your browser even if it returns the transform url. If the image isn't created, check if the file path for your asset source is correct (guess it is if you can upload images), and that url rewriting is working.

Comment: Upload path is correct and is writeable as i have been uploading images to that folder quite happily. Subsequent refreshes don't show the image either. Quite the puzzler!

Comment: Aha! The post you reference says to add 'generateTransformsBeforePageLoad' => true to the config and that is what did the trick. Thanks Andre!

Comment: Ok, that setting should just ensure that the image is created before the first page load, so you'll never see that transform url. I prefer this too, but it should work without it unless there's something else that's wrong.