# Laravel Homestead image transforms 404

Tags: image-transforms

I am running Craft locally using default/update Laravel Homestead/Vagrant box.

Image Transforms are returning the CP resources URL 404 error outlined in this related question:
[Image transforms returning cpresources url](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/827/image-transforms-returning-cpresources-url)

- I've confirmed that my host and vagrant box have the correct permissions
- I've cleared cache and reindexed assets
- I've tried the 'generateTransformsBeforePageLoad' => true,

I still receive the error: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Comment: Are you calculating the dimensions on the fly, by chance? I ran into a similar problem, and eventually determined it was because I was trying to resize to a non-integer pixel value. E.g. if you set a transform like `{ width: image.width, height: (image.width / 2) }` and the image is 555px wide, it will try to resize to 277.5px tall & freak out. Fix by changing to `(image.width / 2)|round`.