# Image transforms return cpresources URL and doesn't apply crop

Tags: image-transforms, craft-features

Despite having tried the tips from [Image transforms returning cpresources url](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/827/image-transforms-returning-cpresources-url), I am still having issues with image-transforms.

the problem is when i put the image without transform it work fine, but when i add the transform parametre it vanish, and even i tried to apply transfom in the template, the image show up but without crop option, only adjust the width and height in the front.

I have tried clearing the cache and db table already as well as updating the asset index. I have double checked the sources paths and it is not a file permission issue.

I am running Craft Pro 2.6.2992

'generateTransformsBeforePageLoad' => true is set in craft/config/general.php

template-code :

```
          {% set  blocWith = "large-12" %}
          {% if block.image.first.url is defined %}
          {% set imageUrl = block.image.first.getUrl('imagewidthlarge') %}
          {% set imageHeight = block.image.first.getHeight('imagewidthlarge') %}
          {% set imageWidth = block.image.first.getWidth('imagewidthlarge') %}

      {% endif %}
              <img src="{{ imageUrl ?? '404' }}" height="{{ imageHeight }}" width="{{ imageWidth }}"/>
              <div class="textBloc">
                {% if block.heading is not empty %}<h2 class="m-b-20" style="color:{{ block.textColor }} !important" >{{ block.heading }}</h2>{% endif %}
                {% if block.subtitle is not empty %}<h3 class="m-b-20"style="color:{{ block.textColor }} !important" >{{ block.subtitle }}</h3>{% endif %}
                {{ include(template_from_string(block.text)|raw) }}
```

this is what the page-source looks like

```
<img src="http://my-site.dev:8080/fr/cpresources/404?x=24sONoMIB" height="483" width="1202">
```

vu front :
[image]

please i'm on a deadline on this projects i tryied all i could to work it out but still, i need this image transform to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did find the solution i checked the basepath with the server hosting my project and it turned out that the relative path dosen't work like the absolute path, so i serached for the root in the server and i inserted the full path, it work !! thanks for letting me know this by myself :)